# how to group by added columns in python

Tags: python, pandas

Previously, I was able to read an excel file to python as a df which contains a column called date in the format like 2011-02-01, and I wanted to get the quarter of each date and group by the data in quarter. I have added a column to the df called quarter, but when I tried

```
df.groupby('quarter')
```

it showed me that

```
No axis named quarter for object type class'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'
```

Is it possible to do the thing I wanted? Or is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Show your code and your excel file

Comment: Yes.  It's completely possible. You need to provide more information about what the dataframe looks like and the code you're using to add the quarter column.

Comment: @piRSquared The dataframe is a big one with thousands of rows of date and other information which I want to groupby. I first converted the date to a datetime type using         df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']), because it was as a series type originally. Then I got the month of each date by  df['month'] = df['Date'].dt.month,     and got the quarter by quarter=(month-1)//3+1 and just added it to the df by df['quarter']=quarter, and I just tried the code I posted above which did not work.

Comment: I think it would have been better to calculate your `quarter` column like this: `df['quarter'] = df['Date'].dt.quarter` and then maybe trying your groupby again.

Comment: @Jarad It works now, thanks!

Comment: @Jarad I didn't know the `dt` accessor had a `quarter` property, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Jarad's answer (in the comments) is very good, but here is another option, which avoids creating a new column:

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(key='Date', freq='Q'))
```

This option is also more flexible. It can be used to group by non-standard periods, e.g. two weeks:

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(key='Date', freq='2W'))
```